# How to sort files and move to their respectable directory (c#)

Tags: split, xelement

So the issue I'm having is if a xml file contains "ONE" then it should move to the credit directory, else move to debit directory. Here is my current solution:

```
private void SplitAndMoveCreditCamts(FileInfo f)
{      
   if (v.Elements().Contains(x => x.Value == "ONE"))
      WriteToDirectory(v, "ONE\\");    
   else    
      WriteToDirectory(v, "TWO\\");
}
```

It does move the files to just the TWO directory. This means that the "WriteToDirectory" method is working, but ignores the "ONE" condition. I believe the error lies there.

Comment: what's v here?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your issue lies within the element line `(v.Elements().Contains(x => x.Value == "ONE"))`

The best solution for you is to make two seperate methods, ONE and TWO, where your `SplitAndMoveONE` is called.

```
private void SplitAndMoveONE(FileInfo f)
        {
            XElement[] els = GetXmlMessages(f.Name);

            foreach (var v in els)
            {
                XNamespace ns = v.Name.Namespace;
                bool exists = v.Descendants(ns + "ONE")
                 .Select(item => item.Value);

                if (exists)
                    WriteToDirectory(v, "ONE\\");
                else
                    // give error message
            }
        }
```

Namespace is vital in order to find the elements in your tag. The same applies to TWO.